# Recursively Looping through N-Nested Dictionaries and creating N+1-Nested Dictionaties

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a file:

```
Key1:
    Key2:
        Key3:
            Key4: Value4
```

I'm reading the file line-by-line:

```
with open(configuration_file) as config_file:
    nested_dict = {}
    for line in config_file:
        dict_reader(line)
```

and for each line it goes through this function `dict_reader` For each line I want to add to a N-Nested dictionary.

```
def dict_reader(line):
    if ": " in line and not ": &" in line and not ": *" in line:
        # create key-value pair, add it to the last empty dictionary in nested_dict   
    if ":" in line and not ": " in line:
        if nested_dict:
            key2 = str(line.split(':')[0].strip())
            d = {key2: {}}

            for k, v in nested_dict.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    v.update(d)
                    break
            print(nested_dict)

        else:
            key1 = str(line.split(':')[0])
            nested_dict[key1] = {}
```

After the first run this returns: `{'Key1': {}}`, which is what I'm after

After the second run this returns: `{'Key1': {'Key2': {}}}` Also what I'm after

But after the third and subsequent runs it returns: `{'Key1': {'Key2': {}, 'Key3': {}}}`. Instead of putting `{'Key3': {}}` as the value to `'Key2'`, it returns it as another element in that dictionary. It does the same thing for `'Key4'` e.g.

`{'Key1': {'Key2': {}, 'Key3': {}, 'Key4': {}}}`

After each line, there should only be one empty dictionary:

```
{'Key1': {}}
{'Key1': {'Key2': {}}}
{'Key1': {'Key2': {'Key3': {}}}}
{'Key1': {'Key2': {'Key3': {'Key4': {}}}}}
 etc.
```

With each loop I want to search the N-nested dictionary, find the first match of an empty dictionary (there will only be one), and update the empty dictionary to be the line I've just read from the file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is this file in Yaml format?

Comment: Yes, but please don't suggest the yaml library. I know of the library, this is not the point of my question.

Comment: My guess is that when you use "v.update(d)" you simply append the new key to the level of key2 instead of putting the new key inside key2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem comes about in the for-loop.

When `v.update(d)` is called on the third pass through the loop

- `d = {'Key3': {}}`
- `v = {'Key2': {}}`

Remember with `k, v` you are looping through the `nested_dict` items, which at that point looks like `{'Key1': {'Key2': {}}}`.

`v.update(d)` changes this to `v = {'Key2': {}, 'Key3': {}}`.

Why? Per the method docstring, `D.update(E)` has a few different behaviours depending on the input. In this case:

> "If E is present and has a .keys() method, then does:  `for k in E: D[k] = E[k]`".

Thus, in this case it just adds the pair `'Key3': {}` to `v`, where `v` really just refers back to the value held in `nested_dict` (which only has one key-value pair at this point).

---

If I understand correctly, in your example you are writing a function that you intend should replicate what the `load` function from the `yaml` library does.

I presume writing it is the *point*, since you don't want to use that library - for the benefit of others it could be done as follows:

```py
import yaml

data = """
Key1:
    Key2:
        Key3:
            Key4: Value4
"""

parsed = yaml.load(data)

# parsed = {'Key1': {'Key2': {'Key3': {'Key4': 'Value4'}}}}
```

---

Since you don't want to do that, instead of `for k, v in nested_dict.items()` you need to go through the dictionary until you reach the deepest level. The problem is, you don't know in advance how many levels that will be. I suggest you could define a function something like this:

```py
def get_deepest_level(d): 
     if not isinstance(d, dict):
         return d  # if the value isn't a dict, just return it
     # otherwise continue:
     for k, v in d.items(): 
         if v: 
             return get_deepest_level(v)  # recursion!
         else: 
             return v
```

This will keep dropping down through the levels of nesting until it encounters a value that either isn't a dictionary, or is an empty dictionary - either of these will be returned at the top level. If you call

```py
deepest_level = get_deepest_level(nested_dict)

deepest_level.update(d)
```

this will update the most deeply-nested dictionary it could find (bearing in mind that there's a loop in there over items that will always drop into your first key-value pair ... but that is what you were doing anyway).

Comment: Thank you so much for a very detailed response!